# can I import a function from other user directory while running the main code as super user?

Tags: python

Using Linux, while the program itself and some other config files are located in one of the user's home directory (and run from there), because of hardware restrictions I am forced to run the main Python code prefixed by *sudo*. Now I want to call a function that already exists in one other Python file inside that user directory.

Simply using `import functionfile` does not seem to work, because (I assume) the program looks for that file in the root directory.

For "normal" tasks such as handling a config file that exists in that user directory, I can recreate the complete path by getting the user that was logged in before launching the *sudo* command, something like:

```
import os
sudo_username = os.getenv("SUDO_USER")
home_dir = "/home/" + sudo_username
```

However, I cannot imagine a method to `import functionfile` from other user directory, especially if I want to avoid absolute reference to usernames.

Is this technically possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, if you import sys and add the directory to sys.path (or alternatively if you modify the PYTHONPATH), and the file is readable by root.

But it may not be a good idea.  It may leave a root-owned .pyc file in that directory that the user cannot overwrite, and it is a huge security hole for a random user to be able to change code that root will be running.